# I want to compare two attribute on form SYMFONY4

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints, symfony4

I have this formtype:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('ageMin', NumberType::class),
            ->add('ageMax', NumberType::class,[
'mapped' => false
]);
    }
```

**My problem**, is i want to validate this expression before submitting the form: ageMin<=ageMax

i HAVE tried this code, but is not work

```
    $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
            'constraints' => [
new Assert\Expression([
                'expression' => 'value["ageMax] >= value["ageMin"]'
            ]),
]
        ]);
```

If there's another solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 'constraints' => [
                new Assert\Expression([
                    'expression' => '
                    (this["ageMin"].getData() <= this["ageMax"].getData() )
                    )
                    ',
                    'message' => ''
                ]),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily solve this by using any one of the following

1. [Constraints Expression](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html)
2. [Custom Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Class Constraint Validator:

```
class UserAgeValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($user, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($user->getAgeMax() >= $user->getAgeMin()) {
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->atPath('ageMin')
                ->addViolation();
            $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
                ->atPath('ageMax')
                ->addViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference to documentation:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator

Comment: that not work, because i ageMax is not mapped with the class, i mean i dont hava getter and setter "ageMax", so you have a solution of this prob?

Comment: @Khalil then add a getter and setter.